# Accessing Salesforce using the Partner API WSDL file and c#

Tags: c#, api, salesforce

I am using **Salesforce web service APIs (Partner API WSDL file)** for retrieving meta data details about Salesforce account objects and records.

In my ***Salesforce*** account I saw few objects only for example 36 objects and my Salesforce service partner api showing 369 objects. I don't why it’s showing like this, and also in my particular specific object meta data showing 65 field ,but in my Salesforce account I saw 38 field only.

I refer this site [Accessing Salesforce using the partner API and C#](https://kzhendev.wordpress.com/2013/12/27/accessing-salesforce-using-the-partner-api-and-c/comment-page-1/#comment-1407)

Comment: You database has multiple tables.  First determine the number of tables in the database.  Then query each table to get the columns and rows.  You then may need to use a JOIN to combine tables by primary keys to get results.

Comment: @jdweng thanks for your comment.In my database only 38 tables are there.but salesforce service partnerapi showing 369 tables.can you please tell some example code.

Comment: Are you sure there are 369 tables, or do you mean 369 columns, or 369 rows?

Comment: @jdweng yes.I am sure there are 369 tables

Comment: Do you know which tables you need to query and what primary keys you need to join the tables?  It looks like the database is using SQL Server.  See : https://kzhendev.wordpress.com/.  So you should have SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) that you can use to test queries and examine the database.  You can use the SSMS explorer to find database and tables.  Then you can right click on the tables which has option to view and create queries.  I often use this to debug database issues.